# Android HTML5 video in Meteor + Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: html, cordova, video, meteor

So I have made a Web app using meteor and it plays videos stored in its public folder quite nicely. The problem is when I build it into a native app for Android, it doesn't seem to be able to find the videos.

Just wondering if anyone knows how to solve this problem. I would like the videos to be stored locally if possible (in the app cache?). I'm currently using a videojs package for meteor. And I've tried different format videos like mp4, ogg and webm.

Cheers!

### Update:

I've managed to find a solution that requires no plugins. Meteor allows you to replace a few Cordova files during the build, by creating a `cordova-build-override` folder under the root project folder. So I've added a file in:

```
cordova-build-override/platforms/android/src/com/{somename}/{appname}/{AppName}.java
```

Then I've gone into the `.meteor/local/cordova-build/{follow same dir as above}` and copied the produced *.java to the file. And added these few lines.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.webkit.Websettings; // This is the added line

public class AppName extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        // The two lines bellow are what I've added.
        WebSettings ws = super.appView.getSettings();
        ws.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
   }
}
```

And this has allowed me to play inline HTML5 videos with videojs in cordova+meteor. And no extra plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova apps work a little differently than standard web apps. Cordova by default does not allow you to play video in your app. You need to add a plugin that extends Cordova with video support. You have 2 options:

1. Use the native android video player via a standard Cordova [plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/391).
2. Use a plugin to allow you to play video through [HTML5 via a local source](https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video).

Try installing one of those and your problem should be solved.

Comment: I've installed option number 2, but I'm still having errors of it not finding the files. I'm not sure if I'm using it right though. I've added the plugin by:
`meteor add cordova:com.jaeger.html5video@https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video/tarball/fe2fcc23de5c5a37c20d4254e7cde51cf09ce567`

And I've added in the code,
`Meteor.startup(function() {
 window.plugins.html5video.initialize({
  "frontViewVideo": "video/mp4/front/1.mp4",
  "sideViewVideo": "video/mp4/side/1.mp4"
 });
})`

Comment: That plugin requires some additional setup to use properly. Check out the documentation on the Github link I provided. A couple of important points you should consider: First, you have to change the android configuration through Cordova to turn on hardware acceleration. Second, the videos can't be in the root public folder like you had them. I am not 100% sure how to integrate this with Meteor, but they need to be in a special place for Cordova to find them. This might not be possible with Meteor! Finally, playback needs to be started from JS directly. Honestly, you may be better with option 1